# Mongoose renaming _id to id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm creating an API that is using data from Mongoose. The front end (Backbone) expects id, instead of _id. I cannot seem to find an easy solution to such a simple problem. Is anyone aware of a way to rename _id to id. I want this to be default behavior across every schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think of setting model.idAttribute to _id on the front end (Backbone). This would allow Backbone to 'transparently map that key to id'.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

Comment: I was thinking about doing this, but someone mentioned that it was poor practice (I don't think so). Do you have any thoughts -- should this be done on the front-end, or should I try to take care of it API side so that all clients don't have to make modifications?

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering when answering. I don't think it is a poor practice. We use it in everyone of our backbone models to map to our backend which requires different ids per model.

Concerning other clients, it really depends on what client/framework you anticipate to use your API but they should be able to adapt to the backend pretty easily in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a schema method `getItem` which returns the desired fields and `id = _id`, if you really need that :)

Comment: any chance you could provide a sample of how I could do this with my schema? https://gist.github.com/4513181